# Php and string concatenation

Tags: php, javascript, html

I don't know why my strings don't concatenate properly.
Here are my 2 files:

---

### scan.php

```
<?php
function scan($directory)
{

$dir = opendir($directory);

$file= readdir($dir);
$file= readdir($dir);
echo "<ul>";
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false)
  {
    $path= $directory . $file;
    if(filetype($path)== "dir")
    {

     echo "<li class='folder' name= ";
     echo $path;
     echo ">";
     echo $file;
     echo"</li>";
    }
    if(filetype($path)== "file") echo "<li class='file' name= ". $path . ">" . $file . "</li>";

  }
  echo "</ul>";
closedir($dir);

}
```

---

### menuNovita.php

```
<?php

 require "scan.php";
  $prefix= "../../novita/";
 scan($prefix); 
 ?>
 <script>
        var scandirectory= 
        var folders= $("li.folder");
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $("li.folder").eq(i).on("mouseenter", {value: $("li.folder").eq(i).attr("name")}, function(event)
        {
            var path= $("li.folder").eq(i).attr("name");
            var string="<div>" + path + "</div>";
            $("#box").after(string);
            string= "<div class='box'>
                <?php 
                require 'scan.php';
                 echo " + path + ";
                scan(" + path + "); ?>
                </div>";
            $("#box:last").after(string);


        };

        </script>
```

I keep getting these errors/warnings:

```
[05-Nov-2012 03:46:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  opendir( + path + ): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /Users/natanconsigli/Desktop/pagina paolo/articoli/novita/scan.php on line 6
[05-Nov-2012 03:46:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/natanconsigli/Desktop/pagina paolo/articoli/novita/scan.php on line 8
[05-Nov-2012 03:46:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/natanconsigli/Desktop/pagina paolo/articoli/novita/scan.php on line 9
[05-Nov-2012 03:46:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/natanconsigli/Desktop/pagina paolo/articoli/novita/scan.php on line 11
[05-Nov-2012 03:46:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  filetype(): Lstat failed for  + path +  in /Users/natanconsigli/Desktop/pagina paolo/articoli/novita/scan.php on line 14
[05-Nov-2012 03:46:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  filetype(): Lstat failed for  + path +  in /Users/natanconsigli/Desktop/pagina paolo/articoli/novita/scan.php on line 23
[05-Nov-2012 03:46:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/natanconsigli/Desktop/pagina paolo/articoli/novita/scan.php on line 11
```

thanks help will be really appreciated.

Comment: I don't see what those errors have to do with strings.  Where did you get that idea?

Answer (score 6):

Your actual error has nothing to do with concatenation, it has to do with this line:

```
scan(" + path + ");
```

The value `+ path +` is passed to `scan()`, which executes `opendir($directory)` (or, `opendir(" + path + ");`). I'm assuming (per your errors), that there is no file named `+ path +`, hence the error you're receiving referring to `opendir()`. All subsequent errors are based off of the initial one.

It looks like you're trying to pass a value from javascript, `path`, to a PHP function. I'm afraid that you're not going to be able to do this without using a bit of ajax, or refreshing the page with query-string variables set.

Comment: Isn't that line part of the non-PHP code that should be output as is (because it is JS)?

Comment: @nnnnnn I said the same thing, then deleted my own reply.  It appears though the OP has gotten his js and php confused in some lights..

Comment: @nnnnnn correct; I've updated to highlight the real error (got confused by the OP's "concatenation" statement as well).

Comment: @nnnnnn        yes. The "+ path +" was supposed to be javascript variable with the path to scan. It looks like it treats it like the string "+path+" instead of adding what path is really supposed to be...

Comment: @user1118686 - You can't access JS variables from PHP. All of the PHP code executes first, on the web-server, and the result is sent to the browser where the JS code is then executed. If you need to do server-side (PHP) processing of values in your JS code then you need to restructure your code so that the JS can submit those values (probably with Ajax).